# archiveArtifacts on windows slave fails

Tags: windows, jenkins, archive

archive artifacts on windows slave fails with this error.  Same is fine on ubuntu slaves.  It feels like some package is missing on windows, but not able to figure out what that is.

`java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream`

Comment: Which error? You didn’t post it...